# I want location of selected DateCell in FSCalendarVIew.How could I get?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fscalendar

I am trying to get location of selected cell in FSCalendarView. (FSCalendar library). Though I am getting location from screen, but its not a perfect location as I want to show popup from that date cell.

I have done something like this, to get touch position,

```
#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerTwoTaps)];
tapGesture.delegate=self;
// Set required taps and number of touches
[tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
CGPoint pointOnScreen = [touch locationInView:nil];
NSLog(@"Point - %f, %f", pointOnScreen.x, pointOnScreen.y);
NSLog(@"Touch");
touchFrame = CGRectMake(pointOnScreen.x, pointOnScreen.y-120, 0, 0);
return NO; // handle the touch
}
```

This is what I am able to achieve from this chunk of code,

[image]

But when I touch lil bit obove the date, I get the position corresponding to that touch and popup s not coming in right spot. Its looking something like this,

[image]

Is there any method to get correct position of date. Any type of help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution after going through all methods available for `FSCalendar`

For those who will come with such requirements, 
There is a method `- (CGRect)frameForDate:(NSDate *)date;` which returns CGRect of selected date, and from this rect, we can find center.

```
- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date {
touchFrame = [calendarView frameForDate:date];
CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(touchFrame.origin.x + (touchFrame.size.width / 2), touchFrame.origin.y + (touchFrame.size.height / 2));

touchFrame.origin = mypoint;
touchFrame.origin.y = touchFrame.origin.y - 120;
touchFrame.size.height = 0;
touchFrame.size.width = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use the delegate method 
`calendar:didSelectDate:atMonthPosition:` and then use `calendar:cellForDate:atMonthPosition:` to get the cell. You can then get the position with cell.frame.